# Explanation with Examples: Finite Subgroup of Rational Numbers Modulo Squares and Its Elements

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, elliptic-curves, quotient-group

Let $\mathbb Q^{\times}/\mathbb Q^{\times^2}$ denote the group of rational numbers modulo squares. This
means that we regard two nonzero rational numbers $x_1, x_2$ as equivalent if the ratio $x_1/x_2$ is the square of a rational number.

Consider the definitions in the following theorem -
[image]

Also the following proposition and corollary-

[image]

Now it is written that Since $\Gamma'$ is finite, but I can't see that how, can anyone explain with simple example of elements of $\Gamma'$? Thanks.

Comment: There are only finitely many $p$ dividing the discriminant, hence only finitely many $n$ live in $\Gamma'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is an answer with an example. Let us consider the sample  elliptic curve with affine equation over the rationals
$$
y^2 = x(x-10)(x-17)\ ,
$$
which has $e_1,e_2,e_3$ equal to $0,10,17$ (in this order, say).

Here are some rational points on the curve, and their maps in $\Bbb Q^\times/(\Bbb Q^\times)^2$. For psychological reasons, a class $\bar a$ of some rational number $a$ in this group (with the inherited multiplication) will be written below as "$a$ modulo squares". Alternatively one can spell $\bar a$ as "$a$ modulo square factors", i.e. the operation we are allowed to do is to get rid of squares in the factorization of $a\in\Bbb Q$, $a\ne 0$. As warming up, we have for instance in this group for the first some random numbers i am choosing:
$$
\begin{aligned}
20 &= 2^2\cdot 5=5&&\text{modulo squares}\\
24 &= 2^3\cdot 3=2\cdot 3&&\text{modulo squares}\\
-4 &=-1&&\text{modulo squares}\\
\frac 23&=2\cdot 3&&\text{modulo squares}\\
1024 &=2^{10}=1&&\text{modulo squares}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on. I think that now the question is answered, but let us go till the end.

The computer is generating some rational points on the given curve. For each point $P$ in the list we compute its image $\delta(P)$ via $\delta$. This image is a triple, and each of its components is (well defined only after it is) taken "modulo squares".

For instance:
$$
\begin{aligned}
T&=(0,0) \\
\delta(T) &=((0-10)(0-17), \ 0-10, \ 0-17)\\
&=(170, -10, 17)&&\text{mod squares,}
\\[2mm]
P&=(1,12)\\
\delta(P) &=(1-0,\ 1-10,\ 1-17))\\
&=(1, -9, -16)=(1,-1,-1)&&\text{mod squares,}
\\[2mm]
Q&=(8,12)\\
\delta(Q) &=(8-0, \ 8-10,\ 8-17))\\
&=(8, -2, -9)=(2,-2,-1)&&\text{mod squares,}
\\[2mm]
R&=(45, 210)\\
\delta(R) &=(45-0, \ 45-10,\ 45-17))\\
&=(45, 35, 28)=(5,35,7)&&\text{mod squares,}
\\[2mm]
S&=(10125, 1017450)\\
\delta(S) &=(10125-0, \ 10125-10,\ 10125-17))\\
&=(3^4\cdot 5^3, \ 5\cdot 7\cdot17^2, \ 2^2\cdot7\cdot19^2)\\
&=(5,35,7)&&\text{mod squares,}\\
\\[2mm]
X&=(a,b)\ ,\text{ with}\\
a&=\frac{75414992906898}{313242821761}\ ,\\
b &=\frac{618120625766999640108}{175316055726018241}\ ,\\
\delta(X) &=(a-0, \ a-10,\ a-17))\\
a-0&=\frac{2\cdot 3^2\cdot 2046881^2}{359^2 \cdot 1559^2}=2
  &&\text{mod squares,}\\
a-10&=\frac{2\cdot 3005881^2}{359^2 \cdot 1559^2 }=2
  &&\text{mod squares,}\\
a-17&=\frac{47^2\cdot 178127^2}{359^2 \cdot 1559^2 }=1
 &&\text{mod squares,}\\
\delta(X)&=(2, 2, 1)
   &&\text{mod squares.}
\end{aligned}
$$
It is maybe good to note that in all cases we have a product of the components in the image triple which is one modulo squares.

Exercise: Compute $\delta(T)$ for the other two torsion points $T=(10,0)$ and $T=(17,0)$.

---

The observation is now that for all values from above of a possible $x_0\in\Bbb Q$ (such that there it can be completed, lifted with an $y_0$...) when we compute
$(x_0-e_1)=(x_0-0)$,
$(x_0-e_2)=(x_0-10)$,
$(x_0-e_3)=(x_0-17)$,
and eliminate all square factors from their factorizations, then the remained primes are among the factors of $\Delta=(0-10)(0-17)(10-17)$. And indeed, such prime factors like $3005881$ in $a-10$ from the last example are constrained to appear to even power. In all computations of a $\delta$-image, we have obtained a number of the shape
$$
(-1)^s2^t5^u7^v17^w
$$
with powers $s,t,u,v,w$ among zero or one.

---

Now the short answer to the question:

The group $\Gamma'$ from the cited result in the OP can thus be seen as, identified as (or injectively mapped to) the group of all $2^5$ numbers of the above form, with multiplication modulo squares as operation. It is a finite group.

In general, we compute $\Delta$, consider its prime factors, count them, if they are $f$, then $\Gamma'$ has $2^{f+1}$ elements, the $+1$ in the power considering the non-square rational unit $(-1)$. The operation is multiplication modulo squares. If we pass to an additive writing, than this group is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/2)^{f+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Gamma’$ is the subgroup generates by the prime divisors of $\Delta$. There are only finitely many such primes. So you have a finitely generated abelian group whose generators all have finite order ($2$) and so the group is itself finite.

Comment: Thank you, could you provide example plz?

Comment: Example of what?

Comment: example of such subgroup with elements, plz?

Comment: Of a finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb Q^\times / (\mathbb Q^\times)^2$? The subgroup generated by $2$ and $3$.